# Bootstrap 3: Show/hide modal when mobile orientation changes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How would you show or hide a Bootstrap modal when mobile orientation changes? e.g.: When device is in landscape, don't show modal, but when device becomes portrait, show modal. I'm thinking about including this functionality in my web apps. I'm sure this is possible, but I'm stumped on where to start.

Comment: and why would you do that when everything in bootstrap is responsive and adjusts itself to any screen. Is there any particular reason??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I just thought it would be a cool functionality, especially with a limited screen space on iPhones, Samsung Galaxy, etc. See this on iPhone: http://s.codepen.io/molarmanful/debug/myNNem - play w/ device orientation

Answer (score 0):

See this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Example try to use orientation : `landscape` , `portrait` to fix model